# I'm using several conditions in my code but it does not check all conditions

Tags: java, android

I'm using several conditions in my code but it does not check all conditions.

Sample of my code:

```
if (securityCodeET.getText().toString().equals("1234")&&
                    accountNoET.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0)
```

When I insert "1234" in `securityCodeET` it moves forward and returns `true` but I think it should give `false` because I haven't put anything in  `accountNoET` .

Comment: Debug your program please. That is way quicker than having us guess what's happening.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

the length of the item returned by the second condition involving accountNoET isn't equal to zero if the the toString() is returning null.

this code is always true if nothing is in that textbox.